# access database from bootstrap zend framework 2 (doctrine2)

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

How I can access to DB from bootstrap using official DoctrineORMModule ?

for example, in my controller:

```
$allusers = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Users\Entity\User')->findAll();
```

but I can't access to getEntityManager() and getRepository() when i'm in bootstrap.

I follow up this guide: http://ivangospodinow.com/zend-framework-2-acl-setup-in-5-minutes-tutorial/

but I'm stuck when trying to connect to db

```
public function getDbRoles(MvcEvent $e){
    // I take it that your adapter is already configured
    $dbAdapter = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

    ...
}
```

Comment: Why are you requesting a database adapter? If you're using doctrine then you would need to fetch the `EntityManager` with `$entityManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');`

Comment: it works $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')->getRepository('Users\Entity\User');
thanks you @AlexP

Answer (score 0):

Using doctrine you would need to fetch the EntityManager with

```
$entityManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

//in my case:
var_dump( $entityManager->getRepository('Users\Entity\User') );
```